# Application Insights telemetry shows 'NA' from MVC 4 application behind private load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-application-insights

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with Application Insights telemetry in my MVC 4 application when it's deployed behind a private load balancer. Locally, the CPU and Memory telemetry is successfully pushed, but when running from a Virtual Machine behind a private load balancer, it shows "NA" as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Initially, I suspected the load balancer, but ongoing requests are indeed being pushed from the VM.

Here's how I've configured Application Insights in my Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DesignHub.WebMvc.Startup))]
public class Startup
{ 
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string appInsightsConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppInsightsConnectionString"];

        Configure Application Insights
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsConnectionString) == false)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy and how to resolve it.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue lies in the IIS Application Pool's identity lacking sufficient permissions to access performance counters, impeding proper monitoring and resource analysis.

**Resolution Steps**:

**Verify Application Pool Identity**:

- Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- Navigate to Application Pools.
- Double-click the relevant Application Pool.
- In the Identity section, note the current user or service account
  under which the pool is running.

**Grant Permissions:**

- Open an elevated Command Prompt window (Run as administrator).
- Execute the following command, replacing PoolName with the actual
  name of your Application Pool:

```
net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" /add "IIS APPPOOL\PoolName"
```

- Press Enter to execute the command. This grants the Application
  Pool's identity membership in the "Performance Monitor Users" group,
  enabling access to performance counters.

**Validate the Fix:**

- Restart the Application Pool (right-click on the pool in IIS Manager
  and select "Restart").
- Attempt to access or collect performance counters after the restart.
  Confirm that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to give permissions to read computer-level performance counter values.

I suggest you give the following troubleshoot guide a try:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/missing-cpu-total-committed-memory-metrics